# Automatize input_fields declaration from a csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

I keep running into the following problem where I need to declare the input_fields of an input file and I have been just copying and pasting from the file into my variable, adding a comma and quotations.  For example:

```
input = ("First Name", "Middle Name", "Last Name")
```

I want to automate this process so that my programs can have a line like this:

```
input = inputize.function1("name_of_file.csv")
```

Where function1 takes the input file ("name_of_file.csv") and returns, in this case a tuple with three strings ("First Name", "Middle Name", "Last Name").  As you can imagine this is a pain right now since I have to do this manually for a lot of files, many of which have very many columns...

I think I want the basic structure to look like the following, but I keep thinking there must be a very simple way to take the first line of a csv file, separate each column header, put quotes around it, and put a comma after it, then store the whole thing as a tuple...

```
def function1(input_file):

  with open(input_file, "rb") as infile:
       for line in infile:
           split = line.split(",")
           for item in split:
               input = '"' + item + '","
           return input
```

I hope this is helpful for other people too since it seems like a common enough/super annoying manual task, and would definitely appreciate any guidance.

**ADDENDUM**

I had been writing code like this:

```
input_fields = ("First Name", "Middle Name", "Last Name")
reader = csv.DictReader(infile, fieldnames = input_fields)
```

Per your answer below, it seems like the top line is moot as all I have to do is:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`DictReader`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) which has a fieldnames property!

```
reader = DictReader(open('name_of_file.csv'))
reader.fieldnames
```

using built in DictReader will help you with some of the nuances involved in parsing csv files.

Comment: Thanks man! Works perfectly. As soon as I can accept your answer (6 minutes), I will do so.